# The usage of something and anything

Tags: grammaticality

I was studying and I saw a sentence that went like this: "Have I done something wrong?"

I was wondering, instead of writing "something", shouldn´t I write "anything", since the sentence is a question?

Thank you people.

Comment: _Anything, anybody, anyone, anywhere,_ and all other combinations with _any_ are [***Negative Polarity Items***](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf), which can't occur except inside the scope of a negative trigger. Questions and _if_-clauses, as well as comparative and superlative constructions, function as negative triggers, Mostly _some_ and _any_ are in complementary distribution, but they can both be used in questions, with slightly different presuppositions.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a shade of difference between

> Have I done something wrong?

and

> Have I done anything wrong?

but that difference is not significant. The word *something* can indicate a *particular* thing which may have done wrong, while the word *anything* is not quite that specific. In other words, *anything* opens up the possibility that any number of things may have been done wrong.

I can also see a person asking about "something" when he or she has just accomplished a task, and another person indicates displeasure in some way. Then, the question "Have I done something wrong?" would be appropriate.

On the other hand, I can also see a person who has completed an *entire* task, asking a person for an opinion about how well he or she did. Then, the question "Have I done anything wrong?" might be more appropriate.

That each sentence is a question has no influence on which word to use, *something* or *anything*. I'd be interested in knowing why you thought it does.

Comment: I saw a sentence in my english book like this: - "John,Could you stay a little longer? I need to talk to you about something".  ( Blank space) - "No, you haven´t done anything wrong"        The space in blank is where I am supposed to write something.

Comment: @moisessoares: To what sentence are you referring?

Comment: The two of them.     This is an exercise of my book where I am supposed to write answers according to the questions below. And one of the questions was - " Jonh, could you stay a little longer? I need to talk to you"  Than I have a blank space to write the answer according to the next saying of his. -" No, you haven´t done anything wrong".  Now I need to figure out a question to write between these two sentences. And then a started to doubt about the meaning of something and anything in the sentece - Have I done (something/anything) wrong?

Comment: And then I started to doubt about the meaning of something and anything in the sentece - Have I done (something/anything) wrong?

Comment: @moisessoares: I see. In that case, either "something" or "anything" would be appropriate in response to the statement "I need to talk to you."

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help.